# How to show if a user is logged in to control panel

Tags: users, control-panel

Is there a way to show if a user is currently logged in to the control panel? As I need a way to see if the client is working in the CMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [MN Snitch](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-snitch) plugin. It probably comes the closest to what you're looking for.